# How to test svg pie charts and graphs using protractor?

Tags: selenium, svg, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I was wondering if some one could direct me how to test svg pie charts and graphs using protractor .

I have to read data on pie charts when hovered on it or read data on graphs when hovered to the data points .

The pie chart is very similar to following one except for the text data. CHeck 2D pie chart example: http://www.fusioncharts.com/charts/pie-doughnut-charts/

Comment: Can you show some of the HTML that displays your SVG?  And any relevant JavaScript?  (How is the data being displayed during hover?)

Comment: My svg is very similar to the following example except for the text they display  : http://www.fusioncharts.com/charts/pie-doughnut-charts/

Comment: Please check 2D Pie chart example

Comment: Have you tried using `browser.actions().mouseMove(element or location).perform()`? Here's some docs for that: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/webdriver/actionsequence.js#L87

Comment: i dont have id's or classes to get the element . I will ask for it and try this

Answer (score 1):

I get the data by xpath - though it's a bit different than normal.  To get access to svg:

```
element(by.xpath('//*[name() = "svg"]//the rest of the path'))
```

Comment: The problem is that you cannot interact - click does not make it happen. And if the path is a curve, perform.click does not work either, because the click is in the middle of the "square" but the curve is not there - therefore with a "ripple-like" plugin you'll realize that the click is somewhere else.
protractor bug? Any solutions?